# Separar cadena en varias columnas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Resulta que estoy intentando separar un nombre por espacios, pero hasta cierto punto he podido realizarlo, ya que cuando el nombre es demasiado largo no logro que me funcione el query, alguien sabe que podría ser? o que estoy haciendo mal

```
SELECT   
    PARSENAME( REPLACE( [1], ' ', '.'), 3) AS T1,
    PARSENAME( REPLACE( [1], ' ', '.'), 2) AS T2,
    PARSENAME( REPLACE( [1], ' ', '.'), 1) AS T3, [1]
FROM DIRECCIONAMIENTO_ANTIOQUIA_COPIA
```

Siendo `[1]` el nombre de mi columna en la BD

[image: Este es el resultado que me da]

Comment: Dependiendo de la versión de SQL que tengas, esto te podria valer o ser una forma de comenzar: `SELECT [1], value FROM DIRECCIONAMIENTO_ANTIOQUIA_COPIA CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([1], ' ')`

Comment: `PARSENAME` está diseñado sólo para hacer Parse de nombre de objetos SQL, los cuales como máximo tienen 4 partes, por eso todos los que tienen más de 4 partes te devuelven todos NULL, porque no es capaz de interpretarlo. Deberías buscar otra forma de hacer lo que buscas sin usar la función `PARSENAME`

Comment: @Marc muchas gracias, no sabia eso, intentare hacerlo mediante un XML que fue la otra forma en la que vi que se podia hacer

Comment: ¿Cuál es la lógica para separar el nombre? Solo veo 3 columnas y si es por espacios se perderían datos.